# Magento 2 js library(Magento_Customer/js/customer-data) how to get custom product attributes in js

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, google-tag-manager

I've a little problem with an override of google tag manager in Magento 2 enterprise.

`google-analytics-universals.js` have some function that trigger the events: addToCart, removeFromCart.

To get the products details in `addtocart` function google tag manager(`google-analytics-universals.js`) use:

```
 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
```

with the method:

```
   items = customerData.get('cart')().items;
```

Unfortunately this method don't retrieve product custom-attribute.

The question is: **which is the best way to retrieve the custom attributes?**

The js of google tag manager and the `customer-data.js` seems to haven't a `phtml` associated that I can use and however I have to get custom attributes only of the product triggered by `addtocart` event in js.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the existing section `Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart`.

The `cart` data comes from it each time when data should be updated:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getSectionData()
{
    $totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals();
    $subtotalAmount = $totals['subtotal']->getValue();
    return [
        'summary_count' => $this->getSummaryCount(),
        'subtotalAmount' => $subtotalAmount,
        'subtotal' => isset($totals['subtotal'])
            ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($subtotalAmount)
            : 0,
        'possible_onepage_checkout' => $this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout(),
        'items' => $this->getRecentItems(),
        'extra_actions' => $this->layout->createBlock(\Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons::class)->toHtml(),
        'isGuestCheckoutAllowed' => $this->isGuestCheckoutAllowed(),
        'website_id' => $this->getQuote()->getStore()->getWebsiteId(),
        'storeId' => $this->getQuote()->getStore()->getStoreId()
    ];
}
```

Pay attention at the `'items'` property. Data about cart items comes from the `getRecentItems` method:

```
/**
 * Get array of last added items
 *
 * @return \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item[]
 */
protected function getRecentItems()
{
    $items = [];
    if (!$this->getSummaryCount()) {
        return $items;
    }

    foreach (array_reverse($this->getAllQuoteItems()) as $item) {
        /* @var $item \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
        if (!$item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
            $product =  $item->getOptionByCode('product_type') !== null
                ? $item->getOptionByCode('product_type')->getProduct()
                : $item->getProduct();

            $products = $this->catalogUrl->getRewriteByProductStore([$product->getId() => $item->getStoreId()]);
            if (isset($products[$product->getId()])) {
                $urlDataObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($products[$product->getId()]);
                $item->getProduct()->setUrlDataObject($urlDataObject);
            }
        }
        $items[] = $this->itemPoolInterface->getItemData($item);
    }
    return $items;
}
```

So you can create a plugin for the `Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\ItemPool` (or interface) for the method `getItemData`, which has access to the original `QuoteItem` (in arguments).

Here how it will be looking, when you add some custom attribute:

#### Here is example:

Define the plugin:

> app/code/MageWorx/ShippingCalculator/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © MageWorx. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\ItemPoolInterface">
        <plugin name="add_custom_attributes_plugin"
                type="MageWorx\ShippingCalculator\Plugin\ItemCustomAttributes"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create plugin class (you should add own logic here):

> app/code/MageWorx/ShippingCalculator/Plugin/ItemCustomAttributes.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © MageWorx. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */

namespace MageWorx\ShippingCalculator\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item;

/**
 * Class ItemCustomAttributes
 */
class ItemCustomAttributes
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\ItemInterface $subject
     * @param array $result
     * @param Item $item
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetItemData($subject, $result, Item $item)
    {
        $result['custom_attribute_1'] = 121;

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Run `setup:di:compile`, clean cache and see a result.

**Note**: you can trigger an update of corresponding section from the browsers console using `require('Magento_Customer/js/customer-data').reload('cart')` command.

[image: Example result with plugin]